# mac python, terminal “print command not found”

Tags: python, macos

[image]

I try use the super admin and use `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top however it also doesn't work

[image]

Actually, I want to open the `.py` document but terminal shows that `print: command not found`.

Comment: You type python code directly into your shell... What you want is to create a new text file, add your python code in there and then just run it from shell via `python thefile.py` or `./thefile.py` (if `+x` is set).

Comment: Firstly, **show the text output here**, don't link to a picture of code. Secondly, in neither of those cases have you actually started the Python shell.

Comment: You don't need to copy and paste the #! characters. If you run /usr/bin/python (or probably just python) you will get a python session. Right now you are still in bash.

Comment: You put the `#!` (shebang) at the top of files, but you don't need it in an interactive shell.  Your problem is that you are still in bash, not in python.  Try typing `python` before doing anything else.

Comment: sorry,My question is not clear,in fact I make a stupid mistake but all you help me to know that.Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Just type `python` in your terminal to invoke the [interactive shell](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter). You gave the command in the bash terminal beginning with `#`, which inactivated the whole line.

If you want to run a python script, then put your code in a file like this:

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "2"
```

Now you can run the code typing `python script.py`.

The first line of the code is the [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27998855/2419215), which specifies which interpreter to use, so you can run your script typing `./script.py`.

Comment: The `#!` is the she-bang line that tells the shell which program to use to interpret the following code. The other `#` signs indicate that the user is in a su shell. Everything's fine with that.

Comment: yes but it doesn't make any sense to use in the terminal

Comment: No doubt. But your answer is still misleading, because uncommentig it (i.e. removing the `#`) will not yield anything functioning.

Comment: but he can start the interactive shell if there's no `#!` in the beginning of the line. My answer is right.

Comment: Did you try starting a program with a `!` in the beginning? Go ahead then. You should probably edit your answer and tell that he has to remove **both** chars to start the interactive shell. You then could elaborate a bit more on the difference between interactive shell and code that is run from a file.

Comment: No, I said, type __just__ `python` in the shell. And then I explained why it didn't work.